# std::condition_variable wait_until lags on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I implemented a very simple task scheduler using `std::condition_variable` and it works fine on Ubuntu Linux without any noticeable delays: when I schedule a task to trigger in 500ms it is actually triggered in almost exactly 500ms.

But on Windows it is a different story: when I schedule a task to trigger in 500ms it is triggered somewhere in the range from ~503ms to ~515ms, "lagging" by ~10ms on average. And it seems to "lag" for this 10ms regardless of the time the task is actually scheduled (1000ms, 500ms, 200ms, whatever).

I know that it is actually fine that `wait_until` and any `sleep` functions "lag" a little (it sleeps for a little more than specified in the parameter), but 10ms seems kinda rough, especially when you schedule your task to go off in, say, 50ms.

The code is available by [this link](https://github.com/AgSmith95/exercises/tree/v0.1/multithreading/task_scheduler).

Do you know why does this happen? Is it possible to improve the situation?

- On my Ubuntu 20.04 Linux I use `c++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`
- On my Windows 10 I use MinGW x64 7.2.0 (upgrading to MinGW x64 9.2.0 didn't help)

I don't really believe it is the compiler versioning issue, though.

Comment: Depending on how your kernel was compiled, the linux timer runs at 100Hz, 250Hz, 300Hz, or 1000Hz. (Given that you see almost exactly 500ms, evidence suggests that you are testing on a 1000Hz kernel.) Windows runs the timer at a much lower 64Hz by default. You can use timeBeginPeriod to ask for a higher timer speed, but be aware that it will come with increased energy usage.

Comment: Use `QueryPerformanceCounter` instead. Also, I did not see where you actually timed the performance of the code.

Comment: @RaymondChen thanks for clarufying. Now I know where to dig.

Comment: @Brandon I didn't measure the performance here and I don't really need it. I just wanted to see how much time has passed since the "start" (in main.cpp). And I kind of get it now that I need to use native Windows API to improve the situation.

Comment: I see in your code that you are using `steady_clock`, try switching to `system_clock` and see if that makes a difference. In Windows it should be implemented internally using `QueryPerformanceCounter`

Comment: @EyalK. I've just tried that. It didn't work. I still see it lags for 10-15ms.